# SQL Server 2008 - Ambiguous column name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to do a join between two tables but I am receiving this error

> Ambiguous column name 'NurseWard'

Code:

```
select 
    @WardID = NurseWard
from 
    dbo.NurseTbl as o
inner join 
    inserted as i on o.NurseID = i.NurseID
```

Comment: You probably have a column `NurseWard` in both your `NurseTbl` and `inserted` tables. Preface the select with the table which has the value you want.

Comment: You should always reference every column with the alias anyway. It makes it clear which table the value comes from and avoids issues like this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like the [`inserted` table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx) in a trigger.  The `inserted` table has the same column names as the original table.  From the linked article:

> The inserted table stores copies of the affected rows during INSERT
>   and UPDATE statements. During an insert or update transaction, new
>   rows are added to both the inserted table and the trigger table. The
>   rows in the inserted table are copies of the new rows in the trigger
>   table.

The query has an alias on both the `NurseTbl` and `inserted` tables, and the `inner join` uses the aliases, but the `select` does not.  You will need to add an alias to the `NurseWard` column in the `select`:

```
select @WardID = o.NurseWard -- or i.NurseWard depending on what you need
from dbo.NurseTbl as o
inner join inserted as i on
o.NurseID = i.NurseID
```